# How do I create useful response to ajax form submit in php

Tags: jquery, dom

I have several forms that are being submitted via jQuery AJAX, that are essentially one way forms, such as contact form, where the receiving PHP file simply generates two emails.

I am trying to figure out how to end the process in a way that sends a suitable reply so that we can trigger a visual confirmation to the user.  I am using jQuery 1.9.1.

My current codes are (JS):

```
var subject = $("input#subject2").val(), ... other vars,

dataString = 'subject=' + subject + '&name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message + '&webpage=' + webpage;

$('#head-form').html("<div id='message'><br><br>Cogitating what you asked....</div>");

$.post("http://mydomain.com/forms/send.php", dataString, function(data) {
   $('#head-form').html(data);
});
```

(PHP):

```
<?php

... create and send email bits ...

echo '<div id='message'><h3>Thanks</h3>We will be in touch soon.</div>';

?>
```

The form submission parts work just fine, messages are sent and when viewed by itself, the send.php ends up displaying the desired text.

However at the form end, the html that the form produces is not being written into the desired div.  It remains with the Cogitating html that was added initially upon the click.

It is probably something simple, but my ajax experience is limited to just two previous uses :(

**Me Bad**

It was a cross domain issue, Firefox wasn't accepting the reply as it came from a sub-domain.

Thanks for all the suggestions.  I did learn a few new ways to skin the cat though

Answer (score 1):

Try using the done function

$.ajax({url: '/'}).done(function(data) {});

Answer (score 1):

Try use replaceWith

```
$("#head-form").replaceWith(data);
```